# Google Cloud Messaging Library for Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I've successfully implemented part of the process involved in sending push notifications : going from google app engine to google cloud messaging using just urlfetch.fetch ..

I have searched the web for libraries for this portion of the process that  would be more robust out of the box than the simple implementation that I have, yet, google changed google cloud messaging about 2 months ago, and everything I've seen is much older than that.

Does a library exist for google app engine to talk with google cloud messaging, that isn't out of date?

Or, does anyone have any suggestions on things to look out for as far as going from your own server to gcm?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23720564/how-to-implement-gcm-http-server-in-python-while-avoiding-my-servers-ip-being-b it points to a library for python gcm

Comment: thanks for the response. I saw that library in my search- that's the only one I've found with any recent updates, only other thing I found was https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gcm-client/ - old, but might be relevant, and it claims it's better than the above library. Just trying to make sure I'm not missing something good that's relevant

Comment: Which language do you intend to use in building your server?

Comment: using python with google app engine